# Pytorch function calling

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to compute a trignometric function using pytorch, but having issues while calling it via function, below is my code:-

```
def func(x,y):
  return torch.exp(torch.sin(x)/x-y)

func(torch.tensor[2,3])



Error:-
TypeError - Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-beb818f912f5> in <module>()
----> 1 func(torch.tensor([2, 3]))

TypeError: newf() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

What is incorrect in this code while calling the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it with unpacking:

```
func(*torch.tensor[2,3])
```

Comment: Edited the question, thanks for letting me know

Comment: @John Edited my asnwer